# Computer keeps trying to boot into Windows 7 after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu on to a computer that was running Windows 7.  I do not want to keep the Windows installation.  log is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TGBq6yMCM9/  After installation the computer keeps trying to load Windows.    Have tried using Boot-Repair but that didn't work.  Boot-Repair log is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TGBq6yMCM9/    The computer is a homebrew with a Foxconn G41MD motherboard.

Comment: Looks like system is UEFI, as you have UEFI install on old MBR partitioning on sda. Normally UEFI uses gpt. Ubuntu allows UEFI install to MBR, but probably should not. You have BIOS boot of Windows on sdb. Boot-Repair did a BIOS boot repair and installed syslinux bootloader not grub. You could use Boot-Repair in UEFI mode and then boot system in UEFI mode, but better to also convert to gpt partitioning which may erase that drive. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html & then reinstall UEFI grub. You also need to edit fstab with new UUID

Comment: sdb started life on the machine as an old drive partitioned and formatted with a bootable Xubuntu on it.   I was going to wipe it for a date drive.    It seems  that the Ubuntu installer copied a mirror of the W7 installation to sdb before installing.  It then made it bootable and reset the BIOS to make it the only auto bootable drive.  The Windows bootloader, of curse ignored the presence of Ubuntu.    Ubuntu was on sda and could be manually booted at startup.  Mystery solved, sdb now wiped and sda restored as autobooting drive.  Incidentally, the BIOS was legacy which made things easier.